# Is it possible to access local file via javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 
            fso.CopyFile("C:\\Program Files\\GM4IE\\scripts\\source.txt","C:\\Program Files\\GM4IE\\scripts\\target.txt", 1);
            fso = null;
            }
            catch (e) {
            alert (e.message);
            }
    }
```

I am getting error : 
**"Automation server can not create object"** on the line where I am creating ActiveXObject instance.
I understand that it's considered very bad to access hard-drive data using javascript but I just need it.
I am using **IE8 , Greasemonkey4IE**  to run my javascript.

Thank you,
Mohit

************************************************

```
    function WriteFile()
    {
       var fso  = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
       fso.CopyFile("C:\\source.txt","C:\\target.txt", 1);
    }
```

I've put the above code inside a simple HTML page and it worked perfect.
http://www.c-point.com/JavaScript/articles/file_access_with_JavaScript.htm
You can find the similar code on above mentioned location.
I modified it a bit, tough.
But when I am trying to run it through **GreaseMonkey4IE** it simply spitting the same error I specified earlier.

---

I did it guys, but thanks a lot for your quick and helpful replies.
All I did is : 
    Go to Tools > Internet options > Security > Custom Level
    Under the ActiveX controls and plug-ins, select Enable for Initializing and Script    ActiveX controls not marked as safe.

Comment: see if you find this useful http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/JavaScript__File_Handling.aspx

Comment: if you want to use mozilla then this is specially for mozilla http://www-archive.mozilla.org/js/js-file-object.html

Comment: @Devjosh I need it specifically for IE.

Comment: if need it specifically for IE then link above is specific to IE only

Answer (score 5):

Using native JavaScript, no, it is not generally possible to access a local file.  Using plugins and extensions like ActiveX, Flash, or Java you can get around this rule, generally with some difficulty.

For some browser and OS specific exceptions to this general rule, you might want to have a look here:

[Local file access with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)

Note that as of late 2012, the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader) has been supported in all major browsers and provides a native JavaScript mechanism for accessing local files *that the user nominates* (via an `input` element or by dropping them into the browser).

This still cannot be used to access an arbitrary file by name/path as in the examples in the original question.

Comment: -1 [`window.requestFileSystem`](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/). You can access the file system

Comment: @Raynos - Check your own reference.  That feature is only available in HTML5, only currently supported by Chrome, and only gives you access to a sandbox which may or may not meet the OP's requirements.  I said in my answer that there are browser- and OS-specific workarounds.  But it is still not *generally* possible to access local files.

Comment: @Quentin - Thanks, noted.

Answer (score 4):

HTML5 File API has multiple ways to access local files.

[`window.requestFileSystem`](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-requesting) allows you to request access to the filesystem. Browser support is very poor on this (Chrome only).

[`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader) is the HTML5 FileReader API that allows you to programatically read files that users select through a `<input type='file' />` Browser support is better on this.

You should use fallbacks like flash and POST to a server for full file access.

Generally reading arbitary files is considered "cheating the browser" so I you'll either have to use secure HTML5, ActiveX or Flash. All 3 of those require user permissions.

Comment: And not at all supported by IE8, which the question states is being used.

Comment: Then he needs to debug his activeX code or use a flash program to access the local system.

Comment: `window.requestFileSystem` only for Sandbox-Folders

Answer (score 0):

After some research I have found:

```
 var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
 //This line will create a xml file on local disk, C drive
 fh = fso.CreateTextFile( "C:\\fileName.xml", true);
 fh.WriteLine("this is going to be written in fileName.xml");
```

This is how we can do it.There are other methods also.

Accessing local file system is very bad thing to do but yes we can do it.

**Automation server can not create object**

To get rid of this error go to **Tools → Internet Options → Security → select Internet icon → click Custom level → select Enable** for Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting.
I have not tested this on any other berowser except IE8, but I am sure it will work.

Comment: I'm getting Permission Denied error while creating a file. But I'm able to create the file manually in the same folder.

Comment: This approach was always proprietary to Windows/IE and in recent years, Microsoft has [phased support out](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/05/06/a-break-from-the-past-part-2-saying-goodbye-to-activex-vbscript-attachevent/).