# Is it possible to create and open a file in local system using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

First I want to create a text file in local system and also add contents to the file, after that I want to open that file.

Can't create file using the code, also want code to open a file from local system. Can any one help me or provide with details that is it possible?

```
<body>

<input type="button" value="create" onclick="createFile()"/>    
  
 <script type="text/javascript"  language="javascript">

      function createFile()
                    {
                      try{
                            var fso,file;
                            fso=new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
                            file=fso.CreateTextFile("D:\\ppp.txt");
                            file.WriteLine("AAAAA");
                            file.close();
                        }
                           catch(err){
                               alert(err.message);
                           }                       
                    }

                  </script>

</body>
```

While running in IE got the error:

> **Automation server can't create object**

running in Chrome got the error:

> **ActiveXObject is not defined**

Comment: I think it is not possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to access local file via javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742848/is-it-possible-to-access-local-file-via-javascript)

Comment: Why your are not using Node.js library. It designed for that purpose only.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not have the rights to read/write the users filesystem. You can just use HTML5 localstorage to save data on the client.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the post 
if you will read it with a cool mind you will get knowlegde

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in javascript , May be you can try Filesystem API which is currently supported in Chrome and Opera. You can read about it more here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/