# How to find the path of the downloaded file from asp.net C# web application for checking the integrity of the downloaded file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, md5

I developing a web application using ASP.NET. The users can download an excel template from the site. Now, i want to check the integrity of the file to check whether the file is the same as that on server and it is not corrupted. I can get md5 hashcodes for the file on the server by identifying the path using server.mappath() method but how can i get the location of the downloaded file to generate and check the hashcodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can i get the location of the downloaded file to generate and
>   check the hashcodes.

You can't. *(and thats a good thing)*. Also, you shouldn't.

You can't access client's system  resources through browser. You may use `ActiveX` *(or [others browser/OS specific](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6743041/961113))* to do something like that **but** a better option would be to just provide the hash with each download and let the user verify the file integrity.