# Querying for removable devices in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, windows, backup

I'm currently creating a small backup utility in JavaScript (running locally from a .js file, not in a browser) than continuously scans for removable devices and makes backups of them. It's basically finished, but I'm unsure how to scan for removable devices.
How do I query for removable devices in a for-loop?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are talking about NodeJS, I do not think that this is possible. Javascript is a client-side language, not a server-side language.

Take a look at NodeJS and this library: https://github.com/nonolith/node-usb. That should put you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm sure that it works though, I've actually found a malicious JS worm (Proslikefan) that does so. Here's a link - https://johannesbader.ch/2016/06/proslikefan/

Comment: It looks like ActiveX is the key to making this work, at least in Javascript. ActiveX is how you access the local system. In this example, an Excel spreadsheet is modified and saved using Javascript's ActiveX object: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sw4ddf8(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: This link may also be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742848/is-it-possible-to-access-local-file-via-javascript

Comment: I'm looking for a JS translation from the VBS code `for each drive in fso.drives`, do you know what I mean?